# How to convert list to tuple and search for max and min

Tags: python

I am currently learning python coding and I come across this qns on a learning site:

Create a function that takes a sequence of inputs (may be a list, a tuple, or just a bunch of inputs).  The function should return the minimum and the maximum of the list.

This are some of the test values that are using:

> > > minmax(5,4) 
> > >       4,5
> > >
> > > minmax(5,4,8,3,5,7,4)
> > >       3,8
> > >
> > > minmax([5,4,6]) 
> > >       4,6
> > >
> > > minmax(5.1,4.2,68.34,129.1,-90.3) 
> > >       -90.3,129.1

And I had tried doing it this way but when the parameter is a list, I can't seems to convert it into a tuple and find the max and min.
Here is what I had tried:

```
def minmax(*a):

    b = tuple(a)

    minNum = min(b)

    maxNum = max(b)

    c = (minNum, maxNum)

    return c
```

When a list is taken in, the return result is `([5, 4, 6], [5, 4, 6])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def minmax(*a):

    if len(a) == 1:  # Single (list, tuple, or scalar) argument
        try:
            return minmax(*a[0])  # Expansion of sequence elements, if possible
        except TypeError:  # Case of minmax(42)
            pass  # The general code below handles this directly

    return (min(a), max(a))

>>> minmax(3, 5, 1, 10)
(1, 10)
>>> minmax([3, 5, 1, 10])
(1, 10)
>>> minmax((42, 123, -12))
(-12, 123)
>>> minmax(42)
42
```

This works in more cases than the built-in `min()` and `max()`, which do not work on a single scalar argument (`min(42)`).

```
>>> min(42)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It is however possible to write a simpler version that behaves like the built-in `min()` and `max()` (see my other answer, for instance).

This works by forcing `min()` to be given strictly more than 1 element, except in the special case of `minmax(42)`, which calls `min((42,))`.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to handle different ways of passing in arguments, you need to have some conditions to handle each case.

```
>>> def minmax(*a):
...     if len(a) == 1 and hasattr(a[0], '__getitem__'):
...         # handle a single sequence passed in
...         return min(a[0]), max(a[0])
...     # handle values passed in
...     return min(a), max(a)
...
>>> minmax(5, 4)
(4, 5)
>>> minmax(5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 4)
(3, 8) 
>>> minmax([5, 4, 6])
(4, 6)
>>> minmax(5.1, 4.2, 68.34, 129.1, -90.3)
(-90.3, 129.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler but slightly less powerful solution that mirrors my other solution is:

```
def minmax(*a):
    if len(a) == 1:  # Single (list or tuple) argument
        return (min(a[0]), max(a[0]))
    return minmax(a)  # Single tuple argument given to minmax()
```

This version forces `min()` to be given a single (list or tuple) argument.

It behaves like the built-in `min()` and `max()`: `min(42)` and `minmax(42)` both raise an exception:

```
>>> minmax(3, 5, 1, 10)
(1, 10)
>>> minmax([3, 5, 1, 10])
(1, 10)
>>> minmax((42, 123, -12))
(-12, 123)
>>> minmax(42)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> min(42)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```